# Magento Web API giving server internal error add products

Tags: rest-api

I tried posting a product to my Magento site through its REST web API. I am using curl. I got this error:

{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5e884238b420f"}

And when I searched for the log file, I found:

```
/var/www/html/var/log/exception.log:[2020-04-04 08:15:52] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5e884238b420f; Message: Property "ShowDefaultNotificationMessage" does not have accessor method "setShowDefaultNotificationMessage" in class "Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface". {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5e884238b420f; Message: Property \"ShowDefaultNotificationMessage\" does not have accessor method \"setShowDefaultNotificationMessage\" in class \"Magento\\CatalogInventory\\Api\\Data\\StockItemInterface\". at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): Property \"ShowDefaultNotificationMessage\" does not have accessor method \"setShowDefaultNotificationMessage\" in class \"Magento\\CatalogInventory\\Api\\Data\\StockItemInterface\". at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"} []
```

I tried searching for what this error meant. I couldn't find much.

This is my curl request:

```
curl -X POST "http://167.179.118.154/index.php/rest/default/V1/products"  -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -d '{"product":{"id":0,"sku":"string","name":"string","attribute_set_id":0,"price":0,"status":0,"visibility":0,"type_id":"string","created_at":"string","updated_at":"string","weight":0,"extension_attributes":{"website_ids":[0],"category_links":[{"position":0,"category_id":"string","extension_attributes":{}}],"stock_item":{"item_id":0,"product_id":0,"stock_id":0,"qty":0,"is_in_stock":true,"is_qty_decimal":true,"show_default_notification_message":true,"use_config_min_qty":true,"min_qty":0,"use_config_min_sale_qty":0,"min_sale_qty":0,"use_config_max_sale_qty":true,"max_sale_qty":0,"use_config_backorders":true,"backorders":0,"use_config_notify_stock_qty":true,"notify_stock_qty":0,"use_config_qty_increments":true,"qty_increments":0,"use_config_enable_qty_inc":true,"enable_qty_increments":true,"use_config_manage_stock":true,"manage_stock":true,"low_stock_date":"string","is_decimal_divided":true,"stock_status_changed_auto":0,"extension_attributes":{}},"bundle_product_options":[{"option_id":0,"title":"string","required":true,"type":"string","position":0,"sku":"string","product_links":[{"id":"string","sku":"string","option_id":0,"qty":0,"position":0,"is_default":true,"price":0,"price_type":0,"can_change_quantity":0,"extension_attributes":{}}],"extension_attributes":{}}],"configurable_product_options":[{"id":0,"attribute_id":"string","label":"string","position":0,"is_use_default":true,"values":[{"value_index":0,"extension_attributes":{}}],"extension_attributes":{},"product_id":0}],"configurable_product_links":[0],"downloadable_product_links":[{"id":0,"title":"string","sort_order":0,"is_shareable":0,"price":0,"number_of_downloads":0,"link_type":"string","link_file":"string","link_file_content":{"file_data":"string","name":"string","extension_attributes":{}},"link_url":"string","sample_type":"string","sample_file":"string","sample_file_content":{"file_data":"string","name":"string","extension_attributes":{}},"sample_url":"string","extension_attributes":{}}],"downloadable_product_samples":[{"id":0,"title":"string","sort_order":0,"sample_type":"string","sample_file":"string","sample_file_content":{"file_data":"string","name":"string","extension_attributes":{}},"sample_url":"string","extension_attributes":{}}],"giftcard_amounts":[{"attribute_id":0,"website_id":0,"value":0,"website_value":0,"extension_attributes":{}}]},"product_links":[{"sku":"string","link_type":"string","linked_product_sku":"string","linked_product_type":"string","position":0,"extension_attributes":{"qty":0}}],"options":[{"product_sku":"string","option_id":0,"title":"string","type":"string","sort_order":0,"is_require":true,"price":0,"price_type":"string","sku":"string","file_extension":"string","max_characters":0,"image_size_x":0,"image_size_y":0,"values":[{"title":"string","sort_order":0,"price":0,"price_type":"string","sku":"string","option_type_id":0}],"extension_attributes":{"vertex_flex_field":"string"}}],"media_gallery_entries":[{"id":0,"media_type":"string","label":"string","position":0,"disabled":true,"types":["string"],"file":"string","content":{"base64_encoded_data":"string","type":"string","name":"string"},"extension_attributes":{"video_content":{"media_type":"string","video_provider":"string","video_url":"string","video_title":"string","video_description":"string","video_metadata":"string"}}}],"tier_prices":[{"customer_group_id":0,"qty":0,"value":0,"extension_attributes":{"percentage_value":0,"website_id":0}}],"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"string","value":"string"}]},"saveOptions":true}'
```

Is it because my JSON is holding dummy data (which I just copied from the Magento Web API documentation)? But I tried modifying some of the values like below, and still got the same response:

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 10,
    "sku": "phone8",
    "name": "iPhone8",
    "attribute_set_id": 0,
    "price": 10,
    "status": 0,
    "visibility": 0,
    "type_id": "string",
    "created_at": "string",
    "updated_at": "string",
    "weight": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "website_ids": [
        0
      ],
      "category_links": [
        {
          "position": 0,
          "category_id": "string",
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "stock_item": {
        "item_id": 0,
        "product_id": 0,
        "stock_id": 0,
        "qty": 0,
        "is_in_stock": true,
        "is_qty_decimal": true,
        "show_default_notification_message": true,
        "use_config_min_qty": true,
        "min_qty": 0,
        "use_config_min_sale_qty": 0,
        "min_sale_qty": 0,
        "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
        "max_sale_qty": 0,
        "use_config_backorders": true,
        "backorders": 0,
        "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
        "notify_stock_qty": 0,
        "use_config_qty_increments": true,
        "qty_increments": 0,
        "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
        "enable_qty_increments": true,
        "use_config_manage_stock": true,
        "manage_stock": true,
        "low_stock_date": "string",
        "is_decimal_divided": true,
        "stock_status_changed_auto": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {}
      },
      "bundle_product_options": [
        {
          "option_id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "sku": "string",
          "product_links": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "sku": "string",
              "option_id": 0,
              "qty": 0,
              "position": 0,
              "is_default": true,
              "price": 0,
              "price_type": 0,
              "can_change_quantity": 0,
              "extension_attributes": {}
            }
          ],
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "configurable_product_options": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "attribute_id": "string",
          "label": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "is_use_default": true,
          "values": [
            {
              "value_index": 0,
              "extension_attributes": {}
            }
          ],
          "extension_attributes": {},
          "product_id": 0
        }
      ],
      "configurable_product_links": [
        0
      ],
      "downloadable_product_links": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "is_shareable": 0,
          "price": 0,
          "number_of_downloads": 0,
          "link_type": "string",
          "link_file": "string",
          "link_file_content": {
            "file_data": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extension_attributes": {}
          },
          "link_url": "string",
          "sample_type": "string",
          "sample_file": "string",
          "sample_file_content": {
            "file_data": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extension_attributes": {}
          },
          "sample_url": "string",
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "downloadable_product_samples": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "sort_order": 0,
          "sample_type": "string",
          "sample_file": "string",
          "sample_file_content": {
            "file_data": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extension_attributes": {}
          },
          "sample_url": "string",
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "giftcard_amounts": [
        {
          "attribute_id": 0,
          "website_id": 0,
          "value": 0,
          "website_value": 0,
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    "product_links": [
      {
        "sku": "string",
        "link_type": "string",
        "linked_product_sku": "string",
        "linked_product_type": "string",
        "position": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {
          "qty": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "product_sku": "string",
        "option_id": 0,
        "title": "string",
        "type": "string",
        "sort_order": 0,
        "is_require": true,
        "price": 0,
        "price_type": "string",
        "sku": "string",
        "file_extension": "string",
        "max_characters": 0,
        "image_size_x": 0,
        "image_size_y": 0,
        "values": [
          {
            "title": "string",
            "sort_order": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "price_type": "string",
            "sku": "string",
            "option_type_id": 0
          }
        ],
        "extension_attributes": {
          "vertex_flex_field": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "media_gallery_entries": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "media_type": "string",
        "label": "string",
        "position": 0,
        "disabled": true,
        "types": [
          "string"
        ],
        "file": "string",
        "content": {
          "base64_encoded_data": "string",
          "type": "string",
          "name": "string"
        },
        "extension_attributes": {
          "video_content": {
            "media_type": "string",
            "video_provider": "string",
            "video_url": "string",
            "video_title": "string",
            "video_description": "string",
            "video_metadata": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "tier_prices": [
      {
        "customer_group_id": 0,
        "qty": 0,
        "value": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {
          "percentage_value": 0,
          "website_id": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveOptions": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that's the issue of Magento 2, they have patch for this as link https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/26056

To bypass the issue, you can remove 'show_default_notification_message' of stock_item in body request.
Hope this will help you

Comment: unfortunately I am still having an error after removing  'show_default_notification_message' ;(;(

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in your body request.

```
"show_default_notification_message": true,
```